# fireEvent.click(button) causing error **Call retries were exceeded at ChildProcessWorker.initialize**

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

One of my unit tests is failing when I'm trying to fire a click event on a component. The component is being rendered and is enabled.

```js
//component

import {makeEncryptedCall} from '../../foo';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const onRedirection = async () => {
    const param = {foo: 'bar'};
    return await c(param)
        .then((data) => {
            history.push('/some-url');
        });
  };
  
  return (
    <>
        <button 
            onClick={onRedirection}
            data-testid='my-button'
        />
    </>
  )
}

// test

it('should fire redirection flow', () => {
  jest.mock('../../foo', () => {
    return {
      makeEncryptedCall: jest.fn(() => {
        const response = {
          ok: true,
          json: () => {
            Promise.resolve({
              data: 'superEncryptedStuff';
            });
          }
        };
        return Promise.resolve(response);
      });
    }
  });
  const component = screen.getByTestId('my-button');
  expect(component).toBeEnabled();
  fireEvent.click(component);
});
```

I tried finding solutions related to *Call retries were exceeded* posted before but they are related to setTimeouts, FakeTimers, or async-mock(which I have already implemented).

Note: The test passes when I comment out fireEvent.click. Test only fails when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by wrapping the fireEvent in a **waitFor** function.

```js
it('should fire redirection flow', async () => {
  jest.mock('../../foo', () => {
    return {
      makeEncryptedCall: jest.fn(() => {
        const response = {
          ok: true,
          json: () => {
            Promise.resolve({
              data: 'superEncryptedStuff';
            });
          }
        };
        return Promise.resolve(response);
      });
    }
  });
  const component = screen.getByTestId('my-button');
  expect(component).toBeEnabled();
  await waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(component));
});
```